# if/else not working as expected

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$posthandlerResult = reserveerForm_posthandler(decideWhichSectionlist());

if($posthandlerResult=='go2paypage'){
    echo 1;
}elseif($posthandlerResult===true){
   echo 2;
}else{
   echo 3;
}
```

This is the value of $posthandlerResult (I did this before I did the if/else):

```
var_dump( $posthandlerResult); // -> bool(true)
```

What am I expecting? An echo with the number 2. However, im getting number 1. I've been looking at this too long now, why wont this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `===`-operator to check for the correct type, too.

The `==` checks, if the two expressions *evaluate to* the same value. Interpreted as a `bool` your string evaluates to `true`.

The first of your operands is a `bool`-value, so the second operand is interpreted as a `bool`, too. A non-empty and not zero string evaluates to boolean `true`.

You can look up the operator-behaviour for `string` and `bool` comparisons here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: The triple equal shouldn't matter, I dont care about type at this point. bool(true) still aint 'go2paypage'

Comment: No, but `bool('go2paypage') == bool(true)`.

Comment: If you could be more precise in which way my explanation is not correct, I'd try to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

When using 'if (true == 'someString')', any string that isn't empty or the value 0, will equate to true (so this if statement will be true), see here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting